# Insert wordpress shortcode after a certain div via jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, shortcode

looking to add a shortcode after a certain div on the page. Is this possible?

This is what I've got so far

```
if ($('.w2dc-field-output-block-categories .w2dc-label-primary a:contains("Analytics")').length > 0) {
    $( '<div class="relatedConsultants"><?php echo do_shortcode('[webdirectory-listings category="105" directory="1" perpage="3" listings_view_grid_columns="3" listings_view_type="grid"]'); ?></div>').insertAfter( ".w2dc-field-output-block-categories" );
}
```

So this is finding the categories section at the bottom and if Analytics is present it will then insert a div and do the shortcode. But I’m getting an error of ‘Invalid or unexpected token’.

Without the php in it the jquery runs fine so how can I get the shortcode to work?

Thanks, Stuart

Comment: You can't directly insert php into your javascript, it's only possible if you write the js part in php too. It seems like your php was interpreted as javascript, that's why you got the unexpected token error (`<?php` isn't a valid js code nor anything inside these tags). You need a server side function to render the shortcode (for exaple, an AJAX call that return the results of the `do_shortcode` to your js, so you can include it to the DOM).

Comment: A good answer was provided here  https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/64010/call-shortcode-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var short_code = "<?php echo do_shortcode('[webdirectory-listings category="105" directory="1" perpage="3" listings_view_grid_columns="3" listings_view_type="grid"]'); ?>";

    if ($('.w2dc-field-output-block-categories .w2dc-label-primary a:contains("Analytics")').length > 0) {
    $( '<div class="relatedConsultants">' + short_code + ' </div>').insertAfter( ".w2dc-field-output-block-categories" );
}
```